# Flutter IDE: show improvement suggestions on IDE

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

So today I was playing with the interactive code editor on Flutter's doc page. I noticed that it has a neat suggestion section like the image:
 
[![enter image description here][1]][1] 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG94Tm.png][1]
 
The strange thing is that my IDEs don't show these. I mean if they add this feature to this interactive playground, there is no reason they don't put it in the extensions for AndroidStudio/Intellij or VSCode. Do you guys know how to enable this on IDEs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try using static analysis. Checkout this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/lint)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is still just a package. Is there an option for the extension itself?

Comment: The package is just a set of rules, those rules are the ones that suggest code changes such as the ones in your images. You can combine this, with an extension I personally use, called `Error Lens` on VS Code, and you will get suggestions inline.